# How do I convert correctly timezones

Tags: r, posixct

I am using the [fasttime](http://www.rforge.net/fasttime/files/) package for its `fastPOSIXct` function that can read character datetimes very efficiently. My problem is that it can only read character datetimes THAT ARE EXPRESSED IN GMT.

```
R) fastPOSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="GMT") #very fast
[1] "2010-03-15 12:31:16.223 GMT"
R) as.POSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="GMT") #very slow
[1] "2010-03-15 12:31:16.223 GMT"
```

Now, say  I have a file with datetimes expressed in "America/Montral" timezone, the plan is to load them (implicitely pretending they are in GMT) and modifying subsequently the timezone attribute without changing the underlying value.

If I use this function, refered in another post:

```
forceTZ = function(x,tz){   
    return(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01",tz=tz), tz=tz))
}
```

I am seeing a bug ...

```
R) forceTZ(as.POSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="GMT"),"America/Montreal")
    [1] "2010-03-15 13:37:17.223 EDT"
```

... because I would like it to be

```
R) as.POSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="America/Montreal")
    [1] "2010-03-15 12:37:17.223 EDT"
```

Is there a workaround ?

EDIT: I know about `lubridate::force_tz` but it is too slow (not point using `fasttime::fastPOSIXct` anymore )

Comment: So, you have `character` input like this: "2010-03-15 12:31:16.223 GMT" and you want a POSIXct object that looks like what?

Comment: Nope I have a `character` in a file that looks like `"2010-03-15 12:37:17.223"` I know the timezone is `America/Montreal` but I want to load it and transform it to `POSIXct` with `fasttime`, this package consider that the string represent a datetime in "GMT", so I have to tell R that the resulting POSIXct object is not "GMT" but "America/Montreal"

Comment: And what do you want the output to be? i.e. what's wrong with the `as.POSIXct` solution you show above?

Comment: @Gsee: The `as.POSIXct`is fine but all the problem is to replace it with the much faster `fastPOSIXct`. + I saw the comment you deleted and updated the function but the result stays the same for me...

Comment: @statquant: 1. Where is this `fasttime` function?  Please name the package so we can find it.  2. I assume you mean `"America/Montreal"`. 3. Have you looked at `force_tz` in `lubridate`?

Comment: @RichieCotton: I edited to show where the package is, and to idicate that I know `force_tz` but what it does is cast to `POSIXlt` and access `tz` afterwards which is much too slow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The smart thing to do here is almost certainly to write readable, easy-to-maintain code, and throw more hardware at the problem if your code is too slow.

If you are desperate for a code speedup, then you could write a custom time-zone adjustment function.  It isn't pretty, so if you have to convert between many time zones, you'll end up with spaghetti code.  Here's my solution for the specific case of converting from GMT to Montreal time.

First precompute a list of dates for daylight savings time.  You'll need to extend this to before 2010/after 2013 in order to fit your dataset.  I found the dates here

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=165

```
montreal_tz_data <- cbind(
  start = fastPOSIXct(
    c("2010-03-14 07:00:00", "2011-03-13 07:00:00", "2012-03-11 07:00:00", "2013-03-10 07:00:00")
  ),
  end   = fastPOSIXct(
    c("2010-11-07 06:00:00", "2011-11-06 06:00:00", "2012-11-04 06:00:00", "2013-11-03 06:00:00")
  )
)
```

For speed, the function to change time zones treats the times as numbers.

```
to_montreal_tz <- function(x)
{
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  is_dst <- logical(length(x))  #initialise as FALSE
  #Loop over DST periods in each year
  for(row in seq_len(nrow(montreal_tz_data)))
  {
    is_dst[x > montreal_tz_data[row, 1] & x < montreal_tz_data[row, 2]] <- TRUE
  }
  #Hard-coded numbers are 4/5 hours in seconds
  ans <- ifelse(is_dst, x + 14400, x + 18000)
  class(ans) <- c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
  ans
}
```

Now, to compare times:

```
#A million dates
ch <- rep("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223", 1e6)
#The easy way (no conversion of time zones afterwards)
system.time(as.POSIXct(ch, tz="America/Montreal"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  28.96    0.05   29.00 

#A slight performance gain by specifying the format
system.time(as.POSIXct(ch, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="America/Montreal"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  13.77    0.01   13.79 

#Using the fast functions
library(fasttime)
system.time(to_montreal_tz(fastPOSIXct(ch)))    
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.51    0.02    0.53
```

As with all optimisation tricks, you've either got a 27-fold speedup (yay!) or you've saved 13 seconds processing time but added 3 days of code-maintenance time from an obscure bug when you DST table runs out in 2035 (boo!).

Answer (score 4):

It's a daylight savings issue: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2010a.html

In 2010 it began on the 14th March in Canada, but not until the 28th March in the UK.

You can use `POSIXlt` objects to modify timezones directly:

```
lt <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="GMT"))
attr(lt,"tzone") <- "America/Montreal"
as.POSIXct(lt)
[1] "2010-03-15 12:37:17 EDT"
```

Or you could use `format` to convert to a string and set the timezone in a call to `as.POSIXct`. You can therefore modify `forceTZ`:

```
forceTZ <- function(x,tz)
{
  return(as.POSIXct(format(x),tz=tz))
}


forceTZ(as.POSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="GMT"),"America/Montreal")
[1] "2010-03-15 12:37:17 EDT"
```

Comment: @statquant It looks like `format` casts to `POSIXlt` too. I don't think you will be able to do this without some text parsing, otherwise you would need to calculate and correct for both timezone offsets and DST changes if you wanted to use a purely numeric solution using only `POSIXct`.

Comment: Do we agree that the only think I would have to change is the `timezone ` attribute but that if I access it on a POSIXct object the underlying value changes and if I access it on a POSIXlt object then... I have to cast which is costly ?

Comment: You can change the `POSIXct` `tzone` with `attr`. The trouble is it computes the time anew when displaying using this new timezone, and the elapsed number of seconds from the unix epoch. On the date in question, the time jumps by 1 hour, so that many seconds later differs, plus it factors in the tz offset. You would have to also modify the number of seconds stored by these offsets in order to get the correct figure.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just add the appropriate number of seconds to correct the offset from GMT?

```
# Original problem
fastPOSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="America/Montreal")
# [1] "2010-03-15 08:37:17 EDT"

# Add 4 hours worth of seconds to the data. This should be very quick.
fastPOSIXct("2010-03-15 12:37:17.223",tz="America/Montreal") + 14400
# [1] "2010-03-15 12:37:17 EDT"
```

Comment: @statquant Do you need to account for daylight saving as well?