# POSIXct and timezone conversion

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, posixct

Once again, I'm struggling with date and times in R.
I have a dataset like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(event.time.utc = structure(c(1471407324, 1489129025, 
1480714809, 1471111613, 1472965336, 1484421419, 1475607466, 1475476528, 
1473041225, 1487378311), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    time.verify = c("15:15:24", "16:57:05", "07:40:09", "05:06:53", 
    "16:02:16", "05:16:59", "05:57:46", "17:35:28", "13:07:05", 
    "10:38:31")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("event.time.utc", 
"time.verify"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ event.time.utc: POSIXct, format: "2016-08-16 22:15:24" "2017-03-09 23:57:05" "2016-12-02 14:40:09" "2016-08-13 12:06:53" ...
 $ time.verify   : chr  "15:15:24" "16:57:05" "07:40:09" "05:06:53" ...
```

I want to convert `event.time.utc` to my local timezone: America/Edmonton (UTC-07:00).  The variable `time.verify` is just to verify the results. First, I verified that my timezone exists:

```
> tzfile <- "F:/PortableApps/R/R-3.4.0/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab"
> tzones <- read.delim(tzfile, row.names = NULL, header = FALSE,
+                      col.names = c("country", "coords", "name", "comments"),
+                      as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE, comment.char = "#")

> tzones %>% filter(str_detect(name, "Edmonton"))
  country      coords             name                      comments
1      CA +5333-11328 America/Edmonton Mountain - AB; BC (E); SK (W)
```

I also verify my default timezone:

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "America/Edmonton"
```

And do the same on my OS:

```
C:\Users\tspeidel>tzutil /g
Mountain Standard Time
```

Ok, so far, so good.  Now I want to convert `event.time.utc` to my timezone:

```
> df$new.time <- as.POSIXct(df$event.time.utc, tz = "America/Edmonton")
> head(df)
       event.time.utc time.verify            new.time
1 2016-08-16 22:15:24    15:15:24 2016-08-16 22:15:24
2 2017-03-09 23:57:05    16:57:05 2017-03-09 23:57:05
3 2016-12-02 14:40:09    07:40:09 2016-12-02 14:40:09
4 2016-08-13 12:06:53    05:06:53 2016-08-13 12:06:53
5 2016-09-03 23:02:16    16:02:16 2016-09-03 23:02:16
6 2017-01-14 12:16:59    05:16:59 2017-01-14 12:16:59
```

and this does not produce what I'm expecting. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
Just to follow-up on this based on the post linked in one of the comments:

```
> df$time.edmonton <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(df$event.time.utc), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Edmonton")
> 
> df$time.la <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(df$event.time.utc), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Los_Angeles")
> 
> df
        event.time.utc time.verify       time.edmonton             time.la
1  2016-08-16 22:15:24    15:15:24 2016-08-16 22:15:24 2016-08-16 21:15:24
2  2017-03-09 23:57:05    16:57:05 2017-03-09 23:57:05 2017-03-09 22:57:05
3  2016-12-02 14:40:09    07:40:09 2016-12-02 14:40:09 2016-12-02 13:40:09
4  2016-08-13 12:06:53    05:06:53 2016-08-13 12:06:53 2016-08-13 11:06:53
5  2016-09-03 23:02:16    16:02:16 2016-09-03 23:02:16 2016-09-03 22:02:16
6  2017-01-14 12:16:59    05:16:59 2017-01-14 12:16:59 2017-01-14 11:16:59
7  2016-10-04 12:57:46    05:57:46 2016-10-04 12:57:46 2016-10-04 11:57:46
8  2016-10-03 00:35:28    17:35:28 2016-10-03 00:35:28 2016-10-02 23:35:28
9  2016-09-04 20:07:05    13:07:05 2016-09-04 20:07:05 2016-09-04 19:07:05
10 2017-02-17 17:38:31    10:38:31 2017-02-17 17:38:31 2017-02-17 16:38:31
```

**UPDATE 2**
I seem to get a bit closer by forcing the timezone on the datetime vector:

```
df$event.time.utc <- force_tz(df$event.time.utc, tzone = "UTC")
df$time.edmonton <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(df$event.time.utc), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Edmonton")
df
        event.time.utc time.verify       time.edmonton
1  2016-08-16 22:15:24    15:15:24 2016-08-16 16:15:24
2  2017-03-09 23:57:05    16:57:05 2017-03-09 16:57:05
3  2016-12-02 14:40:09    07:40:09 2016-12-02 07:40:09
4  2016-08-13 12:06:53    05:06:53 2016-08-13 06:06:53
5  2016-09-03 23:02:16    16:02:16 2016-09-03 17:02:16
6  2017-01-14 12:16:59    05:16:59 2017-01-14 05:16:59
7  2016-10-04 12:57:46    05:57:46 2016-10-04 06:57:46
8  2016-10-03 00:35:28    17:35:28 2016-10-02 18:35:28
9  2016-09-04 20:07:05    13:07:05 2016-09-04 14:07:05
10 2017-02-17 17:38:31    10:38:31 2017-02-17 10:38:31
```

**UPDATE 3**
Very close except for DST issues:

```
> df$time.edmonton <- format(df$event.time.utc, tz="America/Edmonton",usetz=TRUE)
> df
        event.time.utc time.verify           time.edmonton
1  2016-08-16 22:15:24    15:15:24 2016-08-16 16:15:24 MDT
2  2017-03-09 23:57:05    16:57:05 2017-03-09 16:57:05 MST
3  2016-12-02 14:40:09    07:40:09 2016-12-02 07:40:09 MST
4  2016-08-13 12:06:53    05:06:53 2016-08-13 06:06:53 MDT
5  2016-09-03 23:02:16    16:02:16 2016-09-03 17:02:16 MDT
6  2017-01-14 12:16:59    05:16:59 2017-01-14 05:16:59 MST
7  2016-10-04 12:57:46    05:57:46 2016-10-04 06:57:46 MDT
8  2016-10-03 00:35:28    17:35:28 2016-10-02 18:35:28 MDT
9  2016-09-04 20:07:05    13:07:05 2016-09-04 14:07:05 MDT
10 2017-02-17 17:38:31    10:38:31 2017-02-17 10:38:31 MST
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting the time component of `new.time` to be the same as `time.verify`

Comment: Even if I do: `df$new.time <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(df$event.time.utc), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Edmonton")` it does not change.

Comment: Yet, if I use America/Los_Angeles (not what I want) it substracts one hour: `df$new.time <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(df$event.time.utc), origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/Los_Angeles")`

Comment: I think I found a solution which I post shortly. It's because of not defining your timezone.

Comment: See update #2 where I force the tz `df$event.time.utc <- force_tz(df$event.time.utc, tzone = "UTC")`.  It does get me closer.
`

Comment: That's basically my solution (defining the timezone explicitly). Other differences that you see are because of daylight saving that you did not take into account in `time.verify`.

Comment: Happy to accept it if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem in the structure of your data. You need to define the timezone, otherwise it will be your system timezone. SO that's you need to do on your `df` first;

```
#This is how I originally made the tzone to be UTC
df$event.time.utc <- as.POSIXlt(df$event.time.utc)
attr(df$event.time.utc, "tzone") <- "UTC"
df$event.time.utc <- as.POSIXct(df$event.time.utc)

#Your solution using lubridate package and force_tz function also works
require(lubridate)
df$event.time.utc <- force_tz(df$event.time.utc, tzone = "UTC")
```

If you define the timezone in your data structure that would alter their values; but with this approach you will just change the timezone and not the time itself.

About the differences in couple of rows between `time.verify` and `time.edmonton` you need to take a look at Daylight Saving differences between Canada and UK.

This **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816534/how-do-i-convert-correctly-timezones)** can be helpful for that.